# Create xml-stylesheet PI with Rails XMLBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby

I want to attach an xslt stylesheet to an XML document that I build with XMLBuilder. This is done with a Processing Instruction that looks like

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='/stylesheets/style.xslt' ?>
```

Normally, I'd  use the `instruct!` method, but `:xml-stylesheet` is not a valid Ruby symbol.

XMLBuilder has a solution for this case for elements using `tag!` method, but I don't see the equivalent for Processing Instructions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this will solve your problem since I don't know the instruct! method of that object, but :'xml-stylesheet' is a valid ruby symbol.

Answer (score 6):

You do it like this:

```
xm.instruct! 'xml-stylesheet', {:href=>'/stylesheets/style.xslt', :type=>'text/xsl'}
```

Just add that line right after

```
xm.instruct! :xml, {:encoding=>"your_encoding_type"}
```

and before the rest of your document output code and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If using the [`atom_feed`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AtomFeedHelper.html#method-i-atom_feed) helper, you can pass this in the `instruct` option:

```
atom_feed(instruct: {
    'xml-stylesheet' => {type: 'text/xsl', href: 'styles.xml'}
  }) do |feed|
  feed.title "My Atom Feed"
  # entries...
end
```

Which results in (showing only first 3 lines):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="styles.xml"?>
<feed xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```